# NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore and In-App-Purchase

Tags: iphone, in-app-purchase, mkstorekit

today I just opened my 1,5 month old project and wanted to add a new In-App-Purchase to the app, so I added all the information to iTunesConnect, didn't change anything for the existing ones. When I now run the app ALL of the purchases won't work, I'm using MKStoreKit but the SKRequest also doesn't throw any errors. In addition I'm getting the following logged in console without adding iCloud support:

```
NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore error: com.mycompany.myapp has no valid com.apple.developer.ubiquity-kvstore-identifier entitlement
```

Any suggestions what is  going on and/or what I could have broken?

Comment: Hi Tim, I am trying to user MKSotreKit as well for the first time. and I am getting the same issue.Any ideas? 10x, benny@applicasa.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm getting the same error.

According to this nice blog: http://troybrant.net/blog/2010/01/in-app-purchases-a-full-walkthrough/, step 7 to be specific, it might take time for Apple to put your new IAP in their sandbox server. So just take a break and come back after a few hours, :)