# In-app purchases MKStoreKit empty available products

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect, in-app, mkstorekit

I've got a problems with in-app purchases with using MKStoreKit.
What already done:

1. App id was already created and tested via test flight
2. All contracts and agreements are valid
3. Created non-consumable in-app purchase (all fields are filled and screenshot attached) 
   status: Waiting for review
4. Created new certificate, provision profile, removed previous build from device
5. Downloaded MKStoreKit and filled needable plist with array "Others" where ["Item 0" : "com.company.appName.inAppId"] and string with SharedSecret key
6. Project's "Bundle identifier" == iTunes Connects' Bundle ID
7. Created sandbox test profile (but, whatever, I cant even receive a list of products)
8. In didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: added

MKStoreKit.sharedKit().startProductRequest()

```
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserverForName(kMKStoreKitProductsAvailableNotification, object: nil, queue: NSOperationQueue()) { (note) -> Void in
        println("products available : \(MKStoreKit.sharedKit().availableProducts)")
    }
```

what I see in console:

> Invalid Product IDs: (
>       "com.company.appName.inAppPurchaseId" )
>
> products available : []

what I have missed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you taken a look at this: [NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore and In-App-Purchase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9018845/nsubiquitouskeyvaluestore-and-in-app-purchase)

If you still have questions or problems you should take a look at video tutorial on Udemy.com. It covers everything you need to know about implementing MKStorekit into your app: http://www.udemy.com/how-to-add-in-app-purchases-to-your-iphone-app-the-easy-way/

Comment: thanks, video preview helps. the reason of failing was in that: my product id was named just like "productId", but should be like "com.company.app.productId"